# передача элемента массива в функцию

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь передать элемент из массива в функцию:

```
u = bezu(mas[j,j],mas[j,i]);
void bezu(int a,int b)
{
}
```

Выдает ошибку:аргумент типа "int *" несовместим с параметром типа "int"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, наверное, у вас `mas` - это `int**`, а поскольку `j,i` есть составной оператор (читай про оператор "запятая"), дающий значение `i`, то `mas[j,i]` - по сути то же, что и `mas[i]`.

Мне просто интересно - неужели глянуть в учебник, и вспомнить, что в C++ обращаться нужно как `mas[j][i]` - это труднее и дольше, чем писать и, простите, позориться на RuSO? Вы же не с небес откровения об языке получаете - ну полистайте книгу! посмотрите в Интернете! ну сделайте хоть что-то *самостоятельно*...

Comment: да,  для начала - если не изучать, то хотябы надо читать...